# Can I write mix code ( Emo Framework and Cocos2d)

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine, box2d-iphone

Can I use [Emo Framework](http://www.emo-framework.com/)  and [Cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) in the same project? Can I write mix code?

Answer (score 0):

Very, very unlikely. Both are OpenGL game engines. Both create their own OpenGL context.

It would be a first for game development. A game made with not one but two game engines.